# Why mkdirs() sometimes returns false - error creating foler

Tags: android, file, permissions, mkdir, mkdirs

I get crashes on my App. I see them in Crashlytics (couldn't reproduce on my devices).

The problem - can't create folder in External Storage using mkdirs()

Note: the code works in 99% of cases (users) and the problem appears only in 1%.

I do have a manifest permission as well I do ask for runtime permissions.

The problem appears mostly on Android 5 versions 
(so runtime permissions are probably not the issue)

My code:

```
String pathTemp = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyApp"
File folderTemp = new File(pathTemp);
if (!folderTemp.mkdirs() && !folderTemp.exists()) {
        throw new AssertionError("Error creating temp folder");
}
```

The crash statistics:
[image]

Comment: full file system? just wild guess...

Comment: No space for an empty folder? They just installed 60MB app and has enough storage. I think it's very unlikely...

Comment: you dont know when it happened... maybe they then downloaded a bunch of pictures of nice looking chicks and then the error occurred?